# How to iterate and reference array of ControlGroup in HTML

Tags: angular

In Angular 2, How do I iterate an array of ControlGroup and reference the Controls within the group?

The [ControlGroup and ControlArray plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/23DESOpbNnBpBHZt1BR4?p=preview) create an array of (empty) city `Control`s:

```
ctrlCities: Control[] = [
    new Control(''),
    new Control(''),
    new Control('')
];
```

wraps them in a `ControlArray`:

```
citiesArray: ControlArray = new ControlArray(this.ctrlCities);
```

and assigns them to the form `ControlGroup` as `citites`:

```
formGroup: ControlGroup = new ControlGroup({
    name: new ControlGroup({
        first: this.ctrlFirst,
        middle: this.ctrlMiddle,
        last: this.ctrlLast
    }),
    food: this.ctrlFood,
    cities: this.citiesArray
});
```

The HTML then iterates the form `ControlGroup`:

```
<form [ng-form-model]="formGroup">
```

and the `cities` `ControlGroup`:

```
    <ul ng-control-group="cities">
```

and finally handles each `Control` in the array of `Control`s:

```
      <li *ng-for="#ctrl of ctrlCities; #i = index"><input ng-control="{{i}}"></li>
```

**If the city controller was a group, how would I reference controls within that group?**

Presumably, I would add

```
ngControlGroup="{{i}}"
```

to my block and then reference the group's individual controls within that block but this results in the following in my application:

```
angular2.dev.js:23597 Error: Cannot find control '0'
    at new BaseException (angular2.dev.js:7464)
    at _throwError (angular2.dev.js:20733)
    at Object.setUpControlGroup (angular2.dev.js:20726)
    at NgFormModel.addControlGroup (angular2.dev.js:16863)
    at NgControlGroup.ngOnInit (angular2.dev.js:16708)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_MarketplaceAddComponent_7.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (viewFactory_MarketplaceAddComponent:2800)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (angular2.dev.js:8156)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (angular2.dev.js:8139)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesContentChildren (angular2.dev.js:8212)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (angular2.dev.js:8140)
```

Any ideas how to do this?

**Aside:** The control APIs are a bit awkward: in the controller new `Control`s are `push`ed to the `ControlArray` (`citiesArray`) but in the view we iterate the array of `Control`s (`ctrlCities`). Why not one or the other?

Comment: [Ahh - got it!](http://plnkr.co/edit/QEdUvvsMTYoxYMXUGYdv?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [an updated plnkr with the solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/QEdUvvsMTYoxYMXUGYdv?p=preview); the controller is modified to use a group for each city with `name` and `size` controls:

```
ctrlCities: ControlGroup[] = [
    new ControlGroup({'name':new Control(''),'size':new Control('')}),
    new ControlGroup({'name':new Control(''),'size':new Control('')}),
    new ControlGroup({'name':new Control(''),'size':new Control('')})
];
```

and the view sets group in the array in a `div` and then references `name` and `size` directly:

```
    <ul ng-control-group="cities">
      <li *ng-for="#ctrl of ctrlCities; #i = index">
      <div ng-control-group="{{i}}">
        <input ng-control="name"> <input ng-control="size">
      </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You should try on a beta version ;-) Your plunkr uses a quite old version (alpha)...

Comment: Ha - thanks, @ThierryTemplier! This is taken directly from the current Angular 2 documentation :-o but I'll see if I can port the plnkr to the latest version.

Comment: Oh my god! Here is a plunkr based on beta15 you can rely on ;-) https://plnkr.co/edit/aG4TdHbAls3cu04AAt64?p=info

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with using @angular2-material & ng2-material in order to leverage the use of md-messages (from ng2-material) and be able to show errors automatically with writing less html codes.

After loosing many hours, I finally understood how you have to use ControlArray with ControlGroups.

Inspired myself of the following plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/23DESOpbNnBpBHZt1BR4?p=preview

The keypoint to understand is that you **ALWAYS** need to nest fields inside the ControlGroup that you defined in your FormBuilder definition, **even** if it is a ControlArray.

I made a plunkr to show how to use it : http://plnkr.co/edit/QX6mjoVNd7ZopsGzmKk7

```js
//our root app component
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {
  Control,
  ControlGroup,
  ControlArray,
  FORM_DIRECTIVES,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators
} from '@angular/common';
import {MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES} from "ng2-material/index";
import {MD_INPUT_DIRECTIVES} from "@angular2-material/input";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  directives: [MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES, MD_INPUT_DIRECTIVES]
  template: `

  <md-card>
    <form name="setProfileForm" [ngFormModel]="setProfileForm">
      <md-card-content>
        <h2>Curriculum vitae</h2>
        <div ngControlGroup="profileInfos">
          <h3>About you</h3>
          <div class="md-input-container">
            <md-input #firstName="ngForm" ngControl="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Firstname"></md-input>
            <div [md-messages]="firstName" role="alert">
              <div md-message="required">Please provide a Firstname!</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="md-input-container">
            <md-input #lastName="ngForm" ngControl="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Lastname"></md-input>
            <div [md-messages]="lastName" role="alert">
              <div md-message="required">Please provide a Lastname!</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div ngControlGroup="positions">
            <h3>Your job positions</h3>
            <div *ngFor="let controlGroup of positionsControlGroup; let i = index" ngControlGroup="{{i}}">
              <h4>Position #{{i+1}}</h4>
              <div class="md-input-container">
                <md-input #company="ngForm" ngControl="company" type="text" placeholder="Company"></md-input>
                <div [md-messages]="company" role="alert">
                  <div md-message="required">Please provide a Company!</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="md-input-container">
                <md-input #title="ngForm" ngControl="title" type="text" placeholder="Title"></md-input>
                <div [md-messages]="title" role="alert">
                  <div md-message="required">Please provide a Title!</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <md-card-actions>
          <button type="submit" md-button md-raised-button class="md-primary" [disabled]="!setProfileForm.valid">Submit</button>
        </md-card-actions>
      </md-card-content>
    </form>
  </md-card>
  `
})
export class App {
  setProfileForm:ControlGroup;
  positionsControlGroup:ControlGroup[];
  positionsControlArray:ControlArray;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.positionsControlGroup = [
      fb.group({
        company: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        title: fb.control(null, Validators.required)
      }),
      fb.group({
        company: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        title: fb.control(null, Validators.required)
      })
    ];

    this.positionsControlArray = fb.array(this.positionsControlGroup);

    this.setProfileForm = fb.group({
      profileInfos: fb.group({
        firstName: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        lastName: fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        positions: this.positionsControlArray
      })
    });
  }
}
```