# Angular 2 - How to access childrens components form ControlGroup

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

I have one top component witch consist of a number of components for example:

```
<div>
<legend>Component A</legend>
<div>
    <label>Value1</label>
    <input ngControl="v1" [(ngModel)]="model.v1" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Value2</label>
    <input ngControl="v1" [(ngModel)]="model.v2" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Value3</label>
    <input ngControl="v1" [(ngModel)]="model.v3" />
</div>
<legend>Component B</legend>
<component-b-form [data]="somedata"></component-b-form>
<legend>Component C</legend>
<component-c-form [data]="somedata"></component-c-form>
<legend>Component D</legend>
<component-d-form [data]="somedata"></component-d-form>
</div>
```

My root component has an form with one ControlGroup and a number of Controls. Each child component has also one form with ControlGroup.

I want to be able to trigger all my child components controlgroups valid method to trigger validation on all my forms.

This could be possible if i could access ControlGroups from root component and call what i need to get validation check.

```
this.controlGroup1 = this.fb.group({
  'v1': ['', Validators.required],
   etc...
});
```

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915769/how-to-iterate-and-reference-array-of-controlgroup-in-html/36916477#36916477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reference your components using `@ViewChild` and access the control group on them:

```
@Component({
})
export class SomeComponent {
  @ViewChild(ComponentBForm)
  componentbForm:ComponentBForm;
  (...)

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let valid = this.componentbForm.form.valid;
    (...)
  }
}
```